# Passing credentials securely between two python applications

Tags: python, json, encryption, flask

I'm looking for some recommendation for the following scenario. The solution that I need to build contains of:

1. Client component written in python that uses requests module to talk to proxy component described under 2. Client will send json data to proxy component and one of the things that we need to send are credentials that will be used between proxy and the final server.
2. "Proxy" component which is a python/Flask based application that

   - Uses https
   - Exposes API style access to receive JSON data from client described under point 1
   - Talks to the final server explained in step 3 by using requests module and requests_ntlm auth to authenticate to server.
3. Server which is a trusted but independent server not controlled by me, running apache or IIS.

The goal is to enable my client to talk to 3rd party server via my proxy flask/python app. Server expect client to perform ntlm authentication which is why proxy flask app uses requests_ntlm module to talk to the server.

However, proxy does not store client's credentials (and I don't need it that way). Ideally client would provide credentials on application start, send those credentials in JSON format to proxy and proxy would use it to obtain response from server after which credentials should be destroyed.

I wonder what kind of approach of exchanging credentials between client and proxy would be the best to use to maximize security and protect as much as one can be protected?

Approach I got so far would be:

1. Client is configured with an "API Key" which is for example 192 characters long.
2. When client talks to proxy, json request is generated in this fashion:

   ```
   { "instruction": "Do this on server", 
     "username": "johndoe", 
     "password": "password in clear text obtained with getpass for example"
     "padding": "random string e.g. 128 - 1024 chars to make sure json payload is
              always different no matter if all other fields are the same"
   }
   ```

   The entire json request is encrypted with the API KEY (open for suggestion about the recommended method for symmetrical encryption of data using a static key).
   Padding is used to make sure json is always different when encrypted. It's a junk data that proxy expects but will ignore as it doesn't contain anything"

User/pass that client is sending is never stored anywhere. When user starts client python app, getpass module is used to get the password, put it into json, encrypt and send it over https and client application can delete variable used with getpass to read password input.

3. Proxy runs flask with https. Client trusts proxy's public key. Proxy also potentially can use address filter to limit who can talk to it in the direction client -> proxy (e.g. just trusted subnets)
4. Proxy expects json to be formatted correctly including having junk padding that's used to ensure randomness of the payload so it is always encrypted differently. Proxy will obtain instruction + user / pass
5. Proxy uses user / pass to open connection to server(s), authenticates with requests_ntlm using credentials provided by client and sends instruction to server (e.g. get me xyz.php?id=123)
6. Results from server are returned as json response from proxy to client using the same api key to encrypt json response + padding to randomise data. Proxy also deletes the variable used to store user/pass that was originally received from client in step 2.
7. Client will be able to read response by decrypting it with the api key stored in the config file or system variable.

What do you think about this approach and what are the areas one could improve security in this setup?

Thank you so much for any advice that you might have and for your time reading this long post.

M.

Comment: Why is it necessary to encrypt the JSON given that is it will be sent over a secure HTTPS connection? What is needed though is to pin the certificate to prevent MITM attacks. But there is the issue of the security of the Proxy server.

Comment: Consider posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) or possible [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/), this forum is about helping with coding issues.

Comment: "Padding is used to make sure json is always different when encrypted" On symmetric encryption padding does not make encryption different, it just makes the data a multiple of the block size. A random IV makes the encryption of the same data with the same key different and can be sent with the encrypted data, generally prepended to the encrypted data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Zaph. My padding is actually a random string of 128-1024 characters. This is why the idea was to use that to make the encrypted payload different every time.